# What is the role of mesosomes?

Tags: cell-biology

Some guide books on biology continue to state that Prokaryotes respire through mesosomes. However, they don't exist in living cells. What is the stand now?

Comment: They are widely considered to be mere artefacts. If you are reading a book that stated otherwise, the book is likely outdated.

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC408341/ --> Fairly recent, give it a go.

Comment: Thanks. The link states " accumulated evidence suggests that mesosomes are not strictly artifacts of chemical fixation...". However, Eli Korvigo commented that they were widely considered to be mere artifacts. It means the research for new evidences are still on.